# Adding the results of multiple queries to a collection and displaying collection in a div

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to run the queries below and return the results line by line in a div.
The results are added to a hashtable which I will be passing to another method and display it in a div.

The first query in array arrayOfQueries[0] can return multiple lines
Que:

1. How can I write this to handle multiple lines returned for the query in this array --- arrayOfQueries[0]. i.e I want to be able to store the multiple lines in the harsh table or maybe I should be using a stringbuilder object.
2. How can I display the content of the hashtable in a div.

   ```
   public Hashtable DisplayResultsToUsers(int genJobId)
   {
       Hashtable myHt = new Hashtable();
       try
       {
           string[] arrayOfQueries = new string[4];
           arrayOfQueries[0] = "select generic, customernumber, productcode from u_generic_data where row_status = 2 and generic_job_id =" + genJobId;
           arrayOfQueries[1] = "select count(*) from u_generic_data where row_status = 2 and generic_job_id =" + genJobId;
           arrayOfQueries[2] = "select count(*) from u_generic_data where row_status = 1 and generic_job_id =" + genJobId;
           arrayOfQueries[3] = "select count(*) from u_generic_data where row_status = 0 and generic_job_id =" + genJobId;

           string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnect"].ConnectionString;

           using (OdbcConnection resConnect = new OdbcConnection(connect))
           {
               string sqlStmt = string.Empty;
               string queryResult = string.Empty;
               int count = 0;
               OdbcCommand dbCmd = new OdbcCommand();
               dbCmd.Connection = resConnect;
               resConnect.Open();

               foreach (string s in arrayOfQueries)
               {
                   dbCmd.CommandText = s;
                   queryResult =  Convert.ToString(dbCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                   count = count + 1;
                   myHt.Add(count, queryResult);
               }

               resConnect.Close();
           }

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {


       }

       return myHt;
   ```

Comment: Where is your div?  How is it expressed through code?  Where are you trying to put it exactly?  Also, don't use a hashtable; just use the array you're starting with (or better yet, a List<string>)

Comment: My div is in my view. I am using a viewmodel which has a property of results. Will a List<string> handle multiple lines? The first query returns 116332 which is wrong. It should return multiple columns.

Comment: Why do you want to ignore exceptions?

Comment: I am not ignoring exceptions. My question is not with exceptions for now. My question is getting the results of my query in a collection and returning it. Thanks.

Comment: Then I recommend you remove that try/catch block. If you were getting exceptions, you wouldn't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dbCmd.ExecuteScalar()` will not work with a query such as `select generic, customernumber, productcode from u_generic_data where row_status = 2 and generic_job_id =" + genJobId`.  You need to do `dbCmd.ExecuteReader()` or some other overload to retrieve those columns.  `ExecuteScalar()` will be fine for the `select count(*)` queries.